# populating nested data in mongoose with ref and ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having these two schema

the below is in a file floor.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var floorSchema = new Schema({
  alias : String,  
  name: String,
  desc: String,
},{timestamps: true});

var floors = mongoose.model('Floor', floorSchema);
module.exports = floors;
```

And in another file facilities.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var k = require('./const')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var facilitySchema = new Schema({
  alias : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  desc: String,
  roomType : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'RoomType'},
  floor : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Floor'},

},{timestamps: true});


var room = mongoose.model('Facility', facilitySchema);
module.exports = room;
```

I will like to populate this by finding with the Facility Model in such a way that the reference ObjectId document is also fetched along with my data as its embedded with the ojectID (I want the data not the objectID)

Here is api end point code in app.js

```
app.get('/api/op/fetch/room2', function(req, res, next){
var Colle = require('./model/facility');
require('./model/floor');
Colle.find().populate('floor').exec( function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    return res.json({status:1, message : data});
});

});
```

Here is the json response

```
[
{
  "_id": "57e758ea2d6f2b73c70e73c4",
  "updatedAt": "2016-09-25T04:56:10.071Z",
  "createdAt": "2016-09-25T04:56:10.071Z",
  "floor": null,
  "roomType": "57e5c0e29f611985910e6a24",
  "desc": "That big room",
  "name": "Room 101",
  "alias": "RM101",
  "__v": 0
}
]
```

The floor object in the above is returning null and not the object from the document. How do I fix this.

The print out on Mongo shell below

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57e758ea2d6f2b73c70e73c4"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-25T04:56:10.071Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-25T04:56:10.071Z"),
"floor" : ObjectId("57e5b9909f611985910e6a1d"),
"roomType" : ObjectId("57e5c0e29f611985910e6a24"),
"desc" : "That big room",
"name" : "Room 101",
"alias" : "RM101",
"__v" : 0
```

Comment: Probably you did not added `floor` id during insert data into `Facility` model. Have tried to see in `mongo` shell?

Comment: Yes I have look through the shell and the id is on the shell, here is print from the floor

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e6bdec89d1333a8c6fea81"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T17:54:52.674Z"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T17:54:52.674Z"), "desc" : "Ile Ijo", "name" : "Ground Floor", "alias" : "Ground;", "__v" : 0 }

Here is what the above json is like without using the ref approach (shorten because of character limit)


  "floor": "57e6bdec89d1333a8c6fea81",
  "roomType": "57e5c0e29f611985910e6a24",
  "desc": "That big room",
  "name": "Room 101",
  "alias": "RM101",
  "__v": 0

Comment: Can you update your question and put output of `mongo` shell for  `db.Floor.find().pretty()` and `db.Facility.find().pretty()` ?

Comment: Thanks Arif Khan, I got it solved. I wasn't have an floor id that correspond with the data I'm embedding just like you suggest in your first comment